# Spring Integration RedisLockRegistry example

Tags: spring

I want to use Spring Integration `RedisLockRegistry` . I have some questions about Spring Integration `RedisLockRegistry`.

1. Can I use the `redisLockRegistry` as a Spring bean ? it means my application just a single `redisLockRegistry`.
2. I see the `RedisLockRegistry` implement `ExpirableLockRegistry` in the version 5.0,

Should I need run the `expireUnusedOlderThan` method?

Comment: Follow these links : 1.  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-redis/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/redis/util/RedisLockRegistryTests.java 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296517/spring-integration-with-redislockregistry-example

Answer (score 1):

I met the same questions and start analyze spring code. So from sources I can state that:

1. Yes you can create and configure it as a bean of any instance of `LockRegistry` like `RedisLockRegistry`, `JdbcLockRegistry`. For test purposes I'd like even use `PassThruLockRegistry`
2. I tried to find any invocation of `expireUnusedOlderThan` inside Spring without success.

So I have created simple scheduler as following:

```
@Autowired
private ExpirableLockRegistry lockRegistry;

@Scheduled(fixedDelay=50000)
public void cleanObsolete(){
    lockRegistry.expireUnusedOlderThan(50000);
}
```